# Android App crashes with java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-play

I have a weird error on my android apps that lead them to crashes.
Basically, when I install an application from android studio directly to my smartphone nothing happens and everything works fine. I have tested it on 3 different devices and the applications work properly. But when it comes to installing these apps from the google play store some of them won't even be able to start.
The error I got from the report is the following:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: 
  at com.google.firebase.platforminfo.LibraryVersion.create (LibraryVersion.java)
  at com.google.firebase.platforminfo.LibraryVersionComponent.create (LibraryVersionComponent.java)
  at com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar.getComponents (AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar.java)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.discoverComponents (ComponentRuntime.java)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.<init> (ComponentRuntime.java)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.<init> (ComponentRuntime.java)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$Builder.build (ComponentRuntime.java)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init> (FirebaseApp.java)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate (FirebaseInitProvider.java)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1940)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1915)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo (FirebaseInitProvider.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6742)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:6289)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6204)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200 (ActivityThread.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1785)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7050)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Lately I have made some changes in the gradle files updating the versions of different libraries. Here are my gradle files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aaa.bbb"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 26
        versionName "2.0.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
            // your project's release build type.
            minifyEnabled true

            // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
            // Android Gradle plugin.
            shrinkResources true

            // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
            // the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
            // R8 configuration files.
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:3.7.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.10'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-directboot'

    implementation 'org.shredzone.commons:commons-suncalc:3.3'
    implementation 'com.github.jesgs:moonfx:v1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:8.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:4.5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0'
    implementation 'jp.hitting.review-manager:review-manager:0.0.1'




    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.8'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url  "https://adcolony.bintray.com/AdColony"
        }
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I really don't understand where the problem is. It seems to be caused by firebase but I don't know how to replicate the issue during development and fix it.

Comment: try running it in release mode from android studio, to see if the same issue. Could be obfuscation related, and if so, check proguard. Did you recently start minifying the app?

Comment: Could you also check the logcat just `above` the exception? it should be related with dalvik

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only crash report I got from Google. There's nothing new added lately related to obfuscation. The only thing I changed was the gradle files.